ASP.NET Core access underlying model in Editor Template
I am upgrading my ASP.NET MVC 5 app to ASP.NET Core MVC. We have heavy use of custom editor templates, in one particular template we want to access the underlying model the view is being passed.
We do that with:
ViewContext.Controller.ViewData.Model

In ASP.NET Core, the Controller property is no longer available, so is there an alternative option?
For example if I have a model
class ViewModel {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

And then have code
Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)

I am trying to access the Id property from inside my Name editor template code.
I can see that the ModelMetadata has a ModelMetadata.ContainerMetadata property which contains information about the model. I can't see how to retrieve values from the Container Model here.
I feel like I should be able to do something like
Html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerMetadata.Properties[0].PropertyGetter(Model)

But I don't know where to get Model (The container model) from.

Do you want to use an editor template to render a model type's properties, like this? :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/display-templates?view=aspnetcore-8.0#editor-templates

Not really, I have added more info.

You can use @Model object directly in a Razor view to access the model passed to the view.:
editor template:
@model TestEditorForModel
<div>
    <label asp-for="Id"></label>
    <input asp-for="Id" />
</div>

<div>
    <label asp-for="Name"></label>
    <input asp-for="Name" />
</div>

Index:
@model TestEditorForModel

@Html.EditorFor(m => m)

Controller:
 public IActionResult Index()
  {
      var model = new TestEditorForModel { Id = 123, Name = "testing editfor" }; 
            
      return View(model);


  }


If @model string is defined in the template and the received string type is returned, you can get the TestEditorForModel instance through ViewData, and then use the Html.EditorFor method to specify the name of the editor template "TestEditorForModel" to render the editor template of TestEditorForModel:
editor template:
@model string
@{
    var fullModel = ViewData["FullModel"] as TestEditorForModel;
}


<div>
    <label asp-for="@fullModel.Id">Id</label>
    <input asp-for="@fullModel.Id"  style="background-color:blue" class="form-control" readonly />

    <label asp-for="@fullModel.Name">Name</label>
    <input asp-for="@fullModel.Name" class="form-control" />
</div>

Index:
@model string 

@{
    var fullModel = ViewData["FullModel"] as TestEditorForModel;

}

<h2>Index</h2>

<form asp-action="Index" method="post">
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m, "TestEditorForModel")
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"save</button>
</form>

controller:
public IActionResult Index()
  {
      var model = new TestEditorForModel { Id = 123, Name = "Initial Value" }; 
      ViewData["FullModel"] = model;
      return View((object)model.Name);


  }



The Model needs to be accessed in the context of an Editor Template, not a view, so the above doesn't work.

In ASP.NET MVC 5, the TemplateInfo class encapsulates the information of the current template context, and it has properties such as HtmlFieldPrefix  and FormattedModelValue, which can be used to prefix HTML fields and get or set formatted model values. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.templateinfo?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2.                            Are you want to implement one of these methods in ASP.NET Core?
